# Amazon S3 static hosting with Namecheap DNS - How to correctly route non-www prefixed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I have been reading other posts to try to get down to the bottom of this issue... but I need some clarification.

I am able to get all of my domain requests to hit my Amazon S3 bucket perfectly when entering `www.example.com/MyDirectory`

If I enter `example.com/MyDirectory` without the www it will fail.

What is the proper method to make URL requests without the www route correctly to the same Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: Check this blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/

Comment: checking this now..

Comment: I was trying to avoid transferring the domain to Amazon Route 53 for the dns. But if this is the best option, then maybe i will need to do this...

Comment: Who is your domain provider? Many times Domain providers also provide functionality to redirect non www to www domain.

Comment: namecheap is the domain provider.

Comment: Ok Your domain provider provides redirect service check out this procedure for name cheap https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/545/51/how-do-i-set-up-url-redirect-when-i-use-your-freedns-service

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I finally came to the following solution:

I am using Namecheap for the DNS and Amazon S3 bucket with static hosting enabled...

The solution enables both the ability to access the root domain and the www domain. In the namecheap advanced DNS configuration I have the following settings:

```
CNAME Record    @    domain.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.
CNAME Record   www   www.domain.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.
```

In the Amazon S3 configuration I have two separate buckets created.

```
[S3 Bucket #1]
Bucket name: www.example.com
Static website hosting set to:
"Enable website hosting"

[S3 Bucket #2]
Bucket name: example.com
Static website hosting set to:
"Redirect all requests to another host name" pointing to www.example.com (Bucket #1)
```

With this configuration any of my web traffic coming in on the root domain can hit the Amazon S3 bucket container `example.com` and then auto redirect via Amazon to the primary S3 bucket `www.example.com` that serves all of my static content.

If someone attempts to connect directly on the www domain it will go directly to the Amazon S3 container `www.example.com` and not need to be redirected thru the `example.com` bucket.

who is running into issues with making your root domain traffic route correctly.

Comment: Interestingly amazon's official documentation entails setting up name records in Route53 and switching to them as DNS provider in your registrar.  @jremi's solution does work though and IMO it's simpler than switching DNS providers! http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: This is not a legal DNS configuration. According to RFC1034, you can't have both a CNAME and other record types filed under the same name. The zone root has at least SOA and NS records, but the problem you're most likely to see with this configuration involves mail routing through MX records. See http://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain.

Comment: How did set up the emails ? 
To forward emails from namecheap to amazon ses ?

Comment: I wish I could help you , but I did not set up the Amazon SES. You will need to look on Google and find hopefully some resources.

Comment: @julienbouteloup - see my answer here.  Using URL redirect for @ I was able to get namecheap email to work.

Comment: @jremi I too have the same setting. Its been around 11 hours since creating the CNAME record. Also, I had bought the domain just recently. Usually how much time does it take to get into affect ??

Comment: @Prathameshdhanawade i have not worked with this for some time.. However, the DNS changes can take time up to 24 hours. This is because it takes time for the DNS to take effect across the internet.

Comment: @jremi Thanks. Got it running. Took about 26 hours.

Comment: For the root domain `@`, you should [use `ALIAS` instead of `CNAME`.](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/579/2237/which-record-type-option-should-i-choose-for-the-information-im-about-to-enter)

Answer (score 53):

So I used jremi's answer but as mentioned below had issues with email being delivered. After some time with NameCheap support, I have a working solution.

NameCheap setup

```
CNAME Record          www   example.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.
URL Redirect Record   @     www.example.com  (unmasked)
```

S3 setup (only need 1 bucket)

```
[S3 Bucket]
Bucket name: www.example.com     <---- This must match your domain exactly
Static website hosting set to:
"Enable website hosting"
```

S3 bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.example.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This has allowed both `example.com` and `www.example.com` to work and my NameCheap email works as well.

Comment: I believe a URL redirect record requires you to specify url including protocol so it'd be ```http://www.example.com```  When I left out ```http://``` I got an error in the Namecheap console saying the url was malformed.

Comment: This is the only valid solution. The most voted solution has several shortcomings.

Comment: [If anyone's wondering - your bucket name HAS to be exactly the same as your domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-create-buckets). @sirclesam isn't doing this just as an example

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, it's now redirecting me to www.example.com even if I enter example.com . Do you know how to make it to stay on example.com?

Answer (score 3):

I used sirclesam's method above and it got me 95% of the way there but my site still wouldn't load until I went and changed some configurations in my AWS S3 console.

Here are the steps to take:

1. navigate to S3 dashboard
2. click on the bucket you want to use (`www.example.com`)
3. click on the 'permissions' nav bar tab
4. a box should appear with two columns and an 'edit' button in the top right corner of the box - click that edit button
5. there should be 4 total checkboxes - UNCHECK the bottom TWO
6. save and then try to access your site

This worked for me. I had initially followed a guide which only indicated that one (the third) checkbox needed to be checked but that resulted in my bucket still blocking access so unchecking the last checkbox was what fixed the issue.

For further clarification, the first checkbox (which should be UNCHECKED) reads:
"Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket policies"
and the second checkbox (which should ALSO be UNCHECKED)reads: "Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket policies"

Comment: Could you document what the bottom two checkboxes were in step 5? Order and number of options may be different if Amazon changes anything. Knowing the specific properties you toggled off would be more helpful.

Comment: @ORyan you bet. 
The first box reads:
"Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket policies"
The second checkbox reads:
"Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket policies"